# Transfer files from mass storage device to other machine via wifi

Tags: wifi, usb

How can one build a device that presents itself as a mass storage device to a machine via usb, then whatever files are transfered to it, get sent to a remote location via wifi (can be ad hoc). Something like the eye-fi but that can send any files.

Something similar to these devices :

http://www.infinitec.com/ (Why can't use : Will be released first of july which is too late for me )

http://www.hsti.com/ (Why can't use : Remote file system is mounted read only)

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You could buy an embedded Linux board with an SD card, a usb port, and a wifi card. Write a script that uses the [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) command to synchronize the contents of the SD card with your remote server over an SSH connection. Set the [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) daemon to execute the rsync script once per minute (or maybe less frequently, depending on the speed of the connection).

You would have to generate an SSH key pair and put the public key on the remote server so that the board could login without a person having to type in a password.

For hardware, I'd try something like one of the following:

1. [Hawkboard](http://www.hawkboard.org/)
2. [Beagleboard](http://beagleboard.org/)
3. [TS-7552](http://www.embeddedarm.com/products/board-detail.php?product=TS-7552)

Comment: to get the specs on the hawkboard, you have to get the 'users manual' (pdf) from the hardware links, and look at section 1.1 - you'd think they'd put this on their page though.

Comment: I already have a couple of ts7800s lying around will use those. My only concern is the mass storage part. I will have to rebuild the kernel to enable USB Gadget so that the ts7800 can present itself as a mass storage device. But that is feasible right ? Or does the TS7552 provide all of this out of the box ?

Comment: I suspect that a TS-7800 will do the job, but you're right that you'll have to do some work to make it appear as a USB storage device. I bet it's been done before, though.

Comment: http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to just "get the job done", I'd go with Linux as suggested. It'll work and be fast.

If you're trying to build something with a low bill of materials, you could consider a microcontroller talking USB mass storage, connected to some non-wifi radio. Then, bridge the radio to ethernet/wifi at the other end. Won't be anywhere near as fast as wifi though.

One approach could be a couple of [jeenodes](http://shop.jeelabs.com/products/jeenode). One running [V-USB](http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html) to talk mass-storage, the other hooked to [ethernet](http://shop.jeelabs.com/products/ether-card).

Comment: +1 for minimalistic spirit. This actually sounds like it would be a lot of fun to integrate. It would also come with a lot of bumps and bruises along the way, no doubt...

Answer (score 1):

If I may make a twist on @Joby's answer, I think you might be able to use a WiShield on an Arduino to get you the wireless aspect. Then I bet there's someone who's made a MassStorage Shield (if not, that might be a good idea for me to try and pull off someday...)

Comment: Teensy + WiShield.
Teensy'll run the LUFA mass-storage code.